# How to specify which hive metastore to connect to?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Going back a few versions of Spark it used to be required to put the

```
 hive-site.xml
```

in the `$SPARK_HOME/conf` directory.  Is that still the case?

The motivation for this question: we are unable to see hive tables that are defined within the metastore instance for which we did copy the `hive-site.xml` to the conf dir.

Comment: Would the specific driver affect *where* the spark gets config from? Should affect the *contents* of the config: e.g. the jdo connection url,etc.

Comment: If you are using derby for hive metastore. It creates metastore_db directory in local from where you started your application.

Comment: That avoids answering the question: we do require a db that is configurable. derby is pure defaults. So assume mysql here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have verified that the `hive-site.xml` is still used. It is selected from the `classpath` of spark. This may be set up via

```
 export SPARK_CLASSPATH=/path/to/conf/dir
```